# How to take mac address of iBeacon in Ionic Framework for the app build on android platform

Tags: ionic-framework, bluetooth-lowenergy, mac-address, scanning

I am trying to build an application for android devices with ionic framework to scan the ibeacons in an environment with the help of https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2015/09/support-ibeacons-in-your-ionic-framework-mobile-app/ . I just want to know few things before stepping into this ionic framework.

```
1. Is it possible to scan ibeacons on android devices without giving UUID's?
2. Is it possible to fetch the mac address of ibeacons on android devices?
```

If the above things are not possible in Ionic Framework, which stack or framework should I use to build an application for android devices to scan both ibeacons and non ibeacons to get the mac address and RSSI?